# Recover grub on encrypted partition without lvm

Tags: grub2, lvm, opensuse, encryption

I have a problem because i need, in rescue system, to mount my encrypted root partition on openSuse leap15.5, but when i try to activate the logical volumes there is no vgchange nor any lvm commands, hence i can’t mount the partition to fix grub.

Any idea?

Thanks, and bests.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need a rescue system that has those commands, or those commands can be installed

Comment: Yeap, I was trying withinna

Comment: Yeap, indeed, I was trying within a shell provided by the installation image, naively believing it was the rescue system. I could use the commands when I figured out how to get into the rescue system. Thanks a lot.